# How can I call a already defined function on keypress?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my code:

```
    $(document).on('click', '.addNewName', function addNewUser() {
        var names = $('.compare_list td:nth-child(1)').map(function () {
            return $(this).text().trim();
        }).get();
        var newname = $('.newname').val();

        if ($.inArray(newname, names) != -1) {
            alert('this name is duplicate');
        } else if (newname == '') {
            alert('enter a name');
        } else {
            $('.compare_list > tbody:last-child').append('<tr><td>'+newname+'</td><td><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></td></tr>');
        }

    })

    // add user by Enter button
    $("#newnam").keypress(function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            addNewUser();
        }
    });
```

When I click on `.addNewName` my code works as well. But when I press enter on keypress of `#newname`, it throws this error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: addNewUser is not defined(…)

Does anybody how can I fix it?

Comment: What are you expecting `this` to be at call to `addUser` within `keypress` event?

Comment: Can you show your html code?

Comment: @guest271314 I have a input *(`type=text`)*, also I have a button *(`value = insert`)* .. Now there is two ways to add the value of that input to the HTML. 1. Clicking on that button, 2. Pressing Enter button on the keyboard.

Comment: @Abk `<input id='newnam' class='newname' type='text' /><br><button class='addNewName'>insert</button>`

Comment: What is issue with current approach?

Comment: Is `#newnam` dynamically created?

Comment: @guest271314 As I've mention in the question, current approach doesn't work, it throws this error `Uncaught ReferenceError: addNewUser is not defined(…)`

Comment: Have you tried approach at Answer? Currently `addNewUser` can only be referenced from within `addNewUser` call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At `javasctipt` at Question `addNewUser` is not defined outside of the scope of `addNewUser` function.

Define `addNewUser` as a named function, set as event handler at `.addNewName` `click` event, call and possibly pass parameters to `addNewUser` within `#newnam` `keypress` event.

```
   function addNewUser() {
      var names = $('.compare_list td:nth-child(1)').map(function() {
        return $(this).text().trim();
      }).get();
      var newname = $('.newname').val();

      if ($.inArray(newname, names) != -1) {
        alert('this name is duplicate');
      } else if (newname == '') {
        alert('enter a name');
      } else {
        $('.compare_list > tbody:last-child')
        .append('<tr><td>' + newname 
          + '</td><td><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></td></tr>');
      }

    }

    // add user by Enter button
    $(document).on("keypress", "#newnam", function(e) {
      if (e.keyCode == 13) {
       addNewUser() // set `this`, pass parameters to `addNewUser`
      }
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.addNewName', addNewUser);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    function addNewUser() {
            var names = $('.compare_list td:nth-child(1)').map(function () {
                return $(this).text().trim();
            }).get();
            var newname = $('.newname').val();

            if ($.inArray(newname, names) != -1) {
                alert('this name is duplicate');
            } else if (newname == '') {
                alert('enter a name');
            } else {
                $('.compare_list > tbody:last-child').append('<tr><td>'+newname+'</td><td><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></td></tr>');
            }

        }
$(document).on('click', '.addNewName', addNewUser);
```

Move function definition of `addNewUser` out of `$(document).on`. Replace it by its name

Comment: I've set a name for that number because I need to call it somewhere else..

Comment: Move function definition of `addNewUser` out of `$(document).on`. Replace it by its name

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use same function on multiple event, make function seperately and call it on whereever you want to call.
Make you AddNewUser function as a seperate function and call it on both element events.

```
function addNewUser() {
        var names = $('.compare_list td:nth-child(1)').map(function () {
            return $(this).text().trim();
        }).get();
        var newname = $('.newname').val();

        if ($.inArray(newname, names) != -1) {
            alert('this name is duplicate');
        } else if (newname == '') {
            alert('enter a name');
        } else {
            $('.compare_list > tbody:last-child').append('<tr><td>'+newname+'</td><td><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></td></tr>');
        }
    }
```

Call it Add new button click

```
$(document).on('click', '.addNewName',function(){
 addNewUser();
});
```

Call it on newnam click keypress

```
$("#newnam").keypress(function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            addNewUser();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function addNewUser() {
        var names = $('.compare_list td:nth-child(1)').map(function () {
            return $(this).text().trim();
        }).get();
        var newname = $('.newname').val();

        if ($.inArray(newname, names) != -1) {
            alert('this name is duplicate');
        } else if (newname == '') {
            alert('enter a name');
        } else {
            $('.compare_list > tbody:last-child').append('<tr><td>'+newname+'</td><td><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></td></tr>');
        }

    }

$(document).on('click', '.addNewName', addNewUser)

    // add user by Enter button
    $("#newnam").keypress(function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            addNewUser();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by this way. Just pass the `$(this)` selector to the function and declare the function outside and call it on multiple events.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.addNewName', function() {
    addNewUser($(this));
});
function addNewUser($THIS) {
    var names = $('.compare_list td:nth-child(1)').map(function() {
        return $THIS.text().trim();
    }).get();
    var newname = $('.newname').val();

    if ($.inArray(newname, names) != -1) {
        alert('this name is duplicate');
    } else if (newname == '') {
        alert('enter a name');
    } else {
        $('.compare_list > tbody:last-child').append('<tr><td>' + newname + '</td><td><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></td></tr>');
    }
}

    // add user by Enter button
$("#newnam").keypress(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    addNewUser($(this));
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just declare the function above `$(document).on('click', function() {})`. Right now you are declaring a named anonymous function. Instead, define it as a top level function.

```
function addNewUser() {
    //...
}

$(document).on('click', '.addNewName', addNewUser );
```

Comment: what about $(this) reference in this case?

Comment: Thank you .. upvote .. your solution is pretty much short, but it contains the right idea.